# Need a second pair of eyes for a CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation, webkit, tween

I have been trying to make a simple drop down animation. I want it to push the other buttons down and display simple text. I got it to work, but I wanted a webkit tween just to jazz it up a bit and I can't seem to get it to work. I don't want to use absolute positioning because I am laying it out like an outline.

Here's a sample of the HTML

```
<div id="ngss-main" class="post">
            <div class="infoblock">
                <a class="topic">Forces and Interactions
                    <div class="inform">
                        <h5>What happens if you push or pull an object harder?</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Pushes and pulls have different strengths and directions</li>
                            <li>Pushes and pulls start, stop, change speed or direction of an object*</li>
                        <ul>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="infoblock">
                <a class="topic">Interdependent Relationships in Ecosystems
                    <div class="inform">
                        <h5>Where do animals live and why do they live there?</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Animals need food, plants need water and light to live and grow</li>
                            <li>Living things need water, air, and resources from their environment</li>
                            <li>Plants and animals can change their environment</li>
                        <ul>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the important part. The CSS

```
.inform {
margin: 5px;
display: none;
color: black;
font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
border:10px solid rgb(114, 145, 63);
background-color: rgb(247, 145, 60);
position: relative;
width: 500px;
top: -200px;
-webkit-animation: slide 0.5s linear;
-moz-animation: slide 0.5s linear;
-0-animation: slide 0.5s linear;
animation: slide 0.5s linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2s;
-o-animation-delay: 2s;
animation-delay: 2s;
}

.inform h5 {
font-style: italic;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 18px;
}

.topic {
font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 24px;
color: rgb(53, 78, 155);
}

.topic li{
color: black;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover .inform  {
display: block;
-webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
0% {top, 0px;}
100% {top, 200px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes slide {
0% {top, 0px;}
100% {top, 200px;}
}
@-o-keyframes slide {
0% {top, 0px;}
100% {top, 200px;}
}
@keyframes slide {
0% {top, 0px;}
100% {top, 200px;}
}
```

I know it's something stupid that I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking more for Transitions, not Animations:

```
.inform {
    margin: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    border:10px solid rgb(114, 145, 63);
    background-color: rgb(247, 145, 60);
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    top: -200px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ktml-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.inform h5 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.topic {
    font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb(53, 78, 155);
}
.topic li {
    color: black;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
a:hover .inform {
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -khtml-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: That's a big step in the right direction, But now it doesn't push the next "topic" down. Do I have to use absolute? Also when I hide it with display: none; then show it with display: block; it gets rid of the transition. Do you know any ways to accomplish that?

Comment: Well I'm trying to get it to look like its coming from behind the "Forces and Interactions" and the other title. What if I were to.

    {max-height:0%;-webkit-transition:max-height 40s ease-in-out;}
    {max-height:100%;}
?

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured it out by now, but anyway... Have you tried adding a pseudo :hover? If not, do so and set a value for height. Now, when you hover over, the container gets stretched down and reveals any additional stuff. May also require playing around with overflow.